# How to customize ion-select popup height in ionic

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to override the `max-height` of a `div` that groups the elements in the popup using [`interfaceOptions`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#interface-options) attribute but I haven't had luck so far, this what I have so far:

```js
 customOptions: Record<string, string> = {
    header: this.translate.instant('mobile.giving.deductionStartDateHeader'),
    cssClass: 'ion-select-max-height'
  };
```

```css
.ion-select-max-height {
 .alert-radio-group {
      max-height: 100%!important;
      }
}
```

```html
<ion-select [interfaceOptions]="customOptions" [formControlName]="fields.deductionStartDate">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor='let date of company.possibleDeductionDates | slice:0:6' [value]="date">
                {{ date | date:'mediumDate' }}
    </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

How can I change the max-height of `div` that has as class `.alert-radio-group`, without overwriting global classes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use `ng-deep` in front of the class I created to pass to `cssClass` attribute then it overrides the class I want to modify in the popup:

```
::ng-deep .ion-select-max-height {
 .alert-radio-group {
      max-height: 100%;
      }
}
```

I'm still learning styling in angular but I read what `ng-deep` does is to force a style down to child components, I saw the `ion-alert` is injected into the DOM, so I guessed it was a child component